# setting bounds or extents of composed plots in HoloViews

Tags: python, bokeh, jupyter-lab, holoviews

Is there some way to set the extents or bounds of individual plots that have been composed in HoloViews? I'm trying to simultaneously display an image and a line plot using the below code. If I set the image's bounds as described below, I can't seem to modify the extents of the line plot; the latter is displayed with axes x = (0, 100) and y = (0, 100). If I don't set the image's bounds, the line plot is displayed with axes x = (0, 10) and y = (-1, 1), but the image is squeezed into only a portion of the axes. I'm using HoloViews 1.10.7 with Bokeh 0.13.0 and Python 3.6.6 in JupyterLab 0.32.0 with jupyterlab_pyviz 0.5.3.

```
import holoviews as hv
import numpy as np

hv.notebook_extension('bokeh')

im = np.random.rand(100, 100)
x0 = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
c0 = hv.Curve((x0, np.sin(x0)), extents=(0, -1, 10, 1))
h = hv.Image(im, bounds=(0, 0, 100, 100))
layout = h+c0
layout
```

Answer (score 1):

Turning on axiswise normalization solved the problem:

```
import holoviews as hv
import numpy as np

hv.notebook_extension('bokeh')

%opts Curve Image {+axiswise}

im = np.random.rand(100, 100)
x0 = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
c0 = hv.Curve((x0, np.sin(x0)))
h = hv.Image(im)
layout = h+c0
layout
```